# Regular expression doesn't match what I would expect

Tags: perl

Using this code:

```
    #!usr/bin/perl
    use strict;
    use warnings;

    my $regExp = "xx\n" .
        "xxfirstonegrabxx\n" .
        "xxx\n" .
        "xxfirstonegrabxx\n" .
        "xxsecondtwotakexx\n" .
        "xxxx";

    if ($regExp =~ /first(.*)?grab.*second(.*)?take/s) {
        print "$1\n";
        print "$2\n";
    }
```

I would expect an output of:

```
    one
    two
```

But I get:

```
    onegrabxx
    xxx
    xxfirstone
    two
```

If I remove the second account of "xxfirstonegrabxx\n" . from $regExp, I get-

```
    one
    two
```

How do I set the regular expression to search top to bottom and to grab just the first occurrence of the pattern?

Using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close. `.*` is, by default, greedy and will match as much as it can. If you modify it with `?` it will become non-greedy and match as little as it can: `.*?`. It looks like you're trying to do that with `(.*)?` but because the `?` is on the outside of the parens the `?` is interpreted as "optional". `(.*)?` means "optionally capture 0 or more of anything, greedily". `(.*?)` means "capture 0 or more of anything, non-greedily".

```
#!usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $regExp = "xx\n" .
    "xxfirstonegrabxx\n" .
    "xxx\n" .
    "xxfirstonegrabxx\n" .
    "xxsecondtwotakexx\n" .
    "xxxx";

if ($regExp =~ /first(.*?)grab.*second(.*?)take/s) {
    say $1;
    say $2;
}
```

The rule of thumb is modifiers like `+` and `?` go inside the capture. It's rare that you want to modify a capture group.

Comment: Thank you Schwern.

Comment: That fixed it! Again thx. I know that this forum is busy and I appreciate that you found my post.

Comment: Two `.*?` in the same pattern raises red flags for me. It means that pattern won't always work as expected.

Comment: @ikegami I've never heard of such a thing. Do you have an example and alternative?

Comment: Most people use `x.*?y` to mean `x[^xy]y`. But what if `x` and `y` are larger patterns? Then you'd have to use `x(?:(?!x|y).)*y`. That's too complicated, and `x.*?y` works fine, if that's the entire pattern. But that breaks down in larger patterns. Is `x.*?y.*m.*?n` equivalent to `x[^xy]*y.*m[^mn]*n`? No. Take `x4z x5y m6n`, for example. Is that the OP's situation? Unclear. Just saying that two `.*?` has never been the correct answer in my experience.

Comment: The `.*` between two `.*?` may altogether be perhaps too "elastic" for me -- I don't know that I could always be sure what that might match.  As for an alternative, one thing would be to break it up, like  `if (/first(.*?)grab/g) { my $c1 = $1; if (/\Gsecond(.*?)take/) { ... }}`